Unable to compile latex on Doom
Running Doom Emacs 3.0 on Emacs 29.1 on macos sequoia 15.2.
After the recent upgrade to the OS and to Emacs, Emacs is correctly highlighting syntax. But I am not able to compile latex documents using Doom commands.
When I open a latex file, syntax is properly highlighted. However, there are no latex commands available in the menu. There is no option for SPC m. There is no SPC m c or SPC m a. There is no +latex/compile command available.
In my init.el file, latex is not commented out.
I am able to compile the document using tex-compile. I am able to compile from command line using xelatex.
What could be going wrong? How do I set it right?

Try to run M-x TeX-command-master (C-c C-c) and select the command. Once it succeeds, try M -x TeX-command-run-all again.

@TianshuWang Thanks. Same outcome. Produces the same error.

M-x toggle-debug-on-error, try again and post the backtrace.

Thanks all. I have not changed anything. But now, suddenly, there is no SPC m commands available. I have updated the question with the latest.

Maybe you're facing the issue described in this report?

@ArashEsbati Thanks. That solved half the problem. Now, I see the SPC m menu. I can compile. But it does not open the PDF viewer like earlier on completion of compilation. I will ask a separate question for that.

I think I had a similar problem with recent Doom update. I solved it like this: (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex\\'" . LaTeX-mode)). Basically, you need LaTeX-mode enabled, it's from AUCTex, I might have put (require 'auctex) as well. Then you can run TeX-command-run-all.

The issue you're facing is related to Doom Emacs and not to AUCTeX.  It is reported here, and the root cause and a workaround are described in this comment.
